# Why map Arduino pins 2 and 3 to Rx and Tx instead of using the build in Rx and Tx pins?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, softwareserial

In many examples I see the following:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

const byte rxPin = 2;
const byte txPin = 3;

// set up a new serial object
SoftwareSerial mySerial (rxPin, txPin);
```

what is the benefit of mapping pins 2 and 3 like this? Why not just use the built in RX (pin 0) and TX (pin 1) pins? I'm using a standard Arduino Uno.

Comment: it allows to have two serial ports ... one can then be used for debugging

Comment: @jsotola  Please do not answer questions in comments - use the answer box for that. Comments here are for seeking more details about the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SoftwareSerial lets you add an additional serial port using "bit banging" to read/write to the port. This lets you connect up another serial device (eg. GPS, RFID reader, MIDI device, LCD) to this extra port, and still use the hardware serial interface (pins 0 and 1) via the USB port to send messages and/or debugging to the connected PC.

---

> Is there any special wiring needed to send messages to the connected PC? Or is it enough that they just not be in use?

Pins 0 and 1 are connected to the Atmega16U2 USB interface chip. If it gets what looks like serial data it will forward it to the PC.

Comment: Is there any special wiring needed to send messages to the connected PC? Or is it enough that they just not be in use?

I'm currently using the hardware ports to communicate with an ESP8266 WiFi module, and I'm still able to see the output of Serial.print() in my serial monitor.

Comment: @AdrianM, but the esp8266 gets your debug prints too. if you have AT firmware in esp8266, the firmware attempts to process them. it disturbs the previous and/or the following AT command

Comment: See my amended answer. I agree with Juraj though, stuff you send through ports 0 and 1 will also go to whatever you have connected to those pins **and** the USB interface.

Answer (score 1):

Nick Gammon indicated Pins 0 (RX) and 1 (TX) are already connected to the USB-Serial 16U2 chip.  Correct.  Although the transmit pin, pin 1, can drive multiple devices / serial ports, the receive pin, pin 0, is being driven by the 16U2 chip.
See: https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-uno-schematic.pdf
Trying to use this would result in tying two outputs together (never good unless the outputs are configured for open collector/open drain).  I've seen many shields that try to use pins 2 and 3 for a serial port.  (Not a good idea for a serial peripheral...)

Comment: Re “_would result in tying two outputs together_”: there is a 1 kΩ resistor between the 16U2’s TX and the 328P’s RX that makes this safe.